# In MySQL will sorting be optimal if columns in index composite select is not fully referenced in sort?

Tags: mysql, indexing

For this question:

- There is a table `foo` with `int` type columns `column1` and `column2`
- There is a composite index `(column1, column2)`
- There are several hundred million rows in `foo`

Using the following:

```
SELECT column2 FROM foo 
 WHERE column1 = 1
 ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

The index `(column1, column2)` is chosen as it fully covers this query.

Assume there are a few hundred thousand entries that match the clause `WHERE column1 = 1`.

If I remove the first parameter of the sort:

```
SELECT column2 FROM foo 
 WHERE column1 IN (1,2,3) 
 ORDER BY column2 ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

The explain confirms it still uses the index.

**Questions**

1. Will the sorting in the `ORDER BY` be negatively impacted by removal of the `column1 ASC` parameter?
2. What if the where clause was `WHERE column1 IN (1,2,3,4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column2 FROM foo 
 WHERE column1 = 1
 ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

can effectively use `INDEX(column1, column2)` in *this* order.  It will be "covering" (unless you add some other column to the `SELECT` list), and it can do the task in 1000 rows, regardless of table size.

But...

```
SELECT column2 FROM foo 
 WHERE column1 IN (1,2,3)   -- More than one value
 ORDER BY column2 ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

can only partially use any index.  Here's how it will be processed:

1. Drill down the BTree for `INDEX(column1, column2)` to find the first row with `column1=1`.
2. Scan forward until the value changes.
3. repeat for column1=2 and again for column1=3.
4. All of the above was collected into a temp table; sort that table
5. peel off the first 100 rows.

Re your Q1, `column1 ASC` is irrelevent:

For query1:  Since column1 is a constant, having it in the `ORDER BY` or not -- does not matter.
For query2:  The results *might* be in a different order.  But rely on this universal rule:  **If you want a particular order, you *must* have an `ORDER BY`**.  Leave it to the Optimizer to "optimizer away" the `ORDER BY` and/or use a particular index if it wants to.

> The explain confirms it still uses the index.

There are multiple reasons for using an index:

- It helps with the `WHERE`.
- It helps with the `ORDER BY`.
- It is "covering"; that is *all* the columns in the query are included in the one composite index.  It might have picked `INDEX(column99, column2, column1)` if you had such!  Then the ordering would be mysterious.

> not fully referenced

- Tacking extra columns on the *end* of an index declaration *usually* does not hurt optimization, but may turn a "fully referenced" query into not fully.
- The "covering" example above is an extreme case of not-fully-referenced.

Another example of various things:

```
WHERE x=1 AND y=2
ORDER BY z
```

is best optimized by `INDEX(x,y,z)` or `INDEX(y,x,z)`.  In this case, both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY` are handled in the index.  Furthermore tacking on a `LIMIT` would allow it to be handled, too.

See my [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of indexes you've defined is very important. Simply, the column you are using in your query, `where query` or `orderby query` should be a prefix of at least one of your indexes. Here, you are defining your index as `column1,column2` and using `column2` which is not a prefix of your index, and therefore it will affect on your query performance. To acieve better performance, you need to define another index for just `column2` To be used when it must be.

Comment: MySQL can only use a single index per table. Index on column2 alone would not be used as the more specific `column1`, `column2` in the where would likely win out.